# Is there any we can set a default search keyword for vi/vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I want to find trailing white spaces(if present) in a file whenever it is opened.For that I want to put default search keyword(pattern to find trailing white space- \s+$)for vi/vim, so that whenever I open any file with vi/vim this default keyword will be searched.Can this be possible ??

Answer (score 2):

I had once thought of that and came up with trailing space. But it only works in `insert mode`, and shows up highlighted trailing spaces.

My .vimrc config for extra whitespace

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
matchExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
:au InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
:au InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
```

and it highlights like this

[image]

To remove white space I am still doing manually by using `sed`

```
:%s/[\ \t]*$//gc
```

(or)

Use `BufWritePre` to run command to remove trailing spaces.

Ref: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces (on your own risk)

Comment: This answer also worked but only insert mode. ThanQ!                                            To remove white space automatically this will help  -  au BufWritePre * %s/\s\+$  .With this trailing white spaces can be removed after :w

Comment: But shows error once no pattern matches. You might have to use the proper one `au BufWritePre * %s/\s\+$//e`

Answer (score 2):

To do exactly what you're asking, you can do

```
au BufReadPost * let @/='\v\s+$'
```

Note that `@/` is global, so it will change the search for all the buffers.

If you only want to highlight trailing spaces, you can do something like that:

```
hi TrailingSpaces ctermbg=red guibg=red
au BufReadPost * call matchadd('TrailingSpaces', '\v\s+$')
```

Comment: The first solution you've provided didn't help me but the second.ThanQ!

Answer (score 1):

For this particular use case (find trailing white spaces), you may want to consider my [ShowTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3966), which is a robust implementation that does *not* clobber the search pattern. (The plugin page has links to many alternative plugins, too.)